# call Procedure inside a Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle9i

i have following structure of a procedures inside a package:

```
PROCEDURE proc_All
(
   start IN date := null,
   end IN date := null,
   cursor1 OUT sys_refcursor,
   cursor1 OUT sys_refcursor,
   cursor1 OUT sys_refcursor
);

PROCEDURE proc_1
(
   start1 IN date := null,
   end1 IN date := null,
   cursor1_1 OUT sys_refcursor,

);   
PROCEDURE proc_3
(
   start2 IN date := null,
   end2 IN date := null,
   cursor1_2 OUT sys_refcursor,

);  
PROCEDURE proc_3
(
   start3 IN date := null,
   end3 IN date := null,
   cursor1_3 OUT sys_refcursor,

);
```

Now my requirement is that i want first procedure proc_All to call all three next procedure, as i want proc_All to be called by program. how can i pass variables to a procedure when calling inside other procedure (weather they are IN or OUT type)

can anyone please help.. thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (though I am not sure you are allowed to use the keyword "end" as a parameter name):

```
PROCEDURE proc_All
(
   start IN date := null,
   end IN date := null,
   cursor1 OUT sys_refcursor,
   cursor1 OUT sys_refcursor,
   cursor1 OUT sys_refcursor
)
IS
BEGIN

  proc_1
  (
     start1 => start,
     end1 => end,
     cursor1_1 => cursor1
  );   

  proc_2
  (
     start2 => start,
     end2 => end,
     cursor1_2 => cursor2
  );   

  proc_3
  (
     start3 => start,
     end3 => end,
     cursor1_3 => cursor3
  );   

END;
```

Comment: thanx for the responce.. its working . but i didnt understood that start and end keywords working

Comment: looks like l_start_date (or) i_start_date should be pretty reasonable based on the data type.